# How to create curved path with arrow head in middle in SVG

Tags: svg

```
I want to create a arrowhead in middle of curved path using SVG. Can someone please help me. below is the sample code of SVG
```

Here I'm trying to create four curved paths. I'm able to create curves. but when I try to use markers it is working with marker-start and marker-end whereas marker-mid is not working as it is single path. Is there a way we can place arrow in middle of the arc

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="325px" height="325px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

    <path d="M80 80
           A 45 45, 0, 0, 0, 125 125
           " stroke="green" fill="none" />
    <path d="M230 80
           A 45 45, 0, 1, 0, 275 125
           " stroke="red" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M80 230
           A 45 45, 0, 0, 1, 125 275
           " stroke="purple" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M230 230
           A 45 45, 0, 1, 1, 275 275
           " stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
</svg>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen there's no marker type that does this. You could do it yourself via javascript.

Use the SVG DOM to determine [the total path length via getTotalLength](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getTotalLength) and then call [getPointAtLength](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#__svg__SVGPathElement__getPointAtLength) with the total path length / 2 to find out the mid point position.

Finally draw whatever you want at that position. If the path changes you'd need to update the pseudo marker position.